# silverlight out of the browser is not showing on desktop

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

my silverlight application is not showing on desktop after instillation it only shows in all programs list. is there something in the configuration or it's about the windows ?

Answer (score 1):

What site?  Did the user select desktop as the shortcut (start menu is the only one enabled by default unless the user checks Desktop as well).